# I dont understand how to optimize Play Store Keywords AND screenshots at the same time

Tags: optimization, google-play, app-store, keyword, experimental-design

I dont understand how to run effective ASO because..

If I am running screenshot experiments I should not be changing text but I need to be changing text to optimize app keywords for App/Play Store search. So I can effectively only do only one or the other?

Please help me understand how this is supposed to be done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can not run effective experiment if you start changing screenshots and keywords at the same time.

Alternatively, you could run an experiment of screen shots in one country and another experiment with keywords in another country at the same time. not all countries are the same so you should choose relatively similar countries from behaviour point of view. One example is US and Australia.

Comment: Wait so if I set up an alt Play Store Page for like India and UK I can run separate experiments for it in parallel?

Comment: Yes, but you can also do this by language. for example 1-English UK | 2-Hindi

Comment: Doesn't that reduce total number of test subjects thereby slowing down both experiments? And also what happens to the rest of the global audience that doesnt fall into either country and is counted as a part of global experiments?